# If $s_n\leqslant t_n$. What we can say about their upper limits?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $s_n\leqslant t_n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. We know that $\liminf  \limits_{n\to \infty}s_n\leqslant \liminf  \limits_{n\to \infty}t_n$.
What we can say about their $\limsup$? Is it real that $\limsup  \limits_{n\to \infty}s_n> \limsup  \limits_{n\to \infty}t_n$? I can't construct such example.

Can anyone give a detailed answer to this question with examples.

Comment: What is a *definition* of the limsup, already?

Comment: @Did, $\limsup \limits_{n\to \infty} a_n=\inf \limits_{k\geqslant 1}\sup \limits_{i\geqslant k} a_i$

Comment: Right, sooo... can you compare $\sup\limits_{i\geqslant k}s_i$ and $\sup\limits_{i\geqslant k}t_i$ for some given $k$, say?

Comment: @Did, I guess that $\sup \limits_{i\leqslant k} s_i \leqslant\sup \limits_{i\leqslant k} t_i$ but I can't prove it strictly.

Comment: An intermediary step, then: if $i\geqslant k$, can you prove that $s_i\leqslant\sup\limits_{j\geqslant k}t_j$?